# Saved variable in Module changes value when recalled in subroutine

Tags: fortran

I am working with a FEM program written in Fortran language. It is a mechanical analysis that involves multiple set of material. The important variables are saved into modules that have the following form

```
MODULE element
  implicit none
  save

  TYPE proel_type
    INTEGER::  prop1
    INTEGER::  prop2
    REAL::     prop3
    REAL::     prop4
    ...
    INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: list1(:)
    REAL, ALLOCATABLE ::    array1(:)
    ...
    INTEGER::  LTYPE
    ...
  END TYPE proel_type

  TYPE(proel_type), ALLOCATABLE:: proel(:)

  INTEGER::  prop1
  INTEGER::  prop2
  REAL::     prop3
  REAL::     prop4
  ...
  INTEGER::  LTYPE
  INTEGER::  ISETS
  ...
END MODULE element
```

As you can see, proel is an allocatable data structure that contains some information about the properties of the material, the element and so on. This data is taken from a text file through a I/O routine like

```
SUBROUTINE setdata
USE element
IMPLICIT NONE

ALLOCATE(PROEL(NSETS))

DO ISETS=1,NSETS

  ... ! here I am loading succefully the string variable STRVAR 
      ! from the text file with data

  LTYPE=GETVAL(STRVAR)    ! here I retreive the value of LTYPE

  PROEL(ISETS)%LTYPE=LTYPE ! here I save the (integer) variable for the set

  IF(LTYPE.NE.0)THEN
    CALL SETELM
  END IF
END DO

END SUBROUTINE
```

Inside subroutine SETELM I am setting some particular parameters used in the program, but at some point I recall LTYPE saved in PROEL

```
SUBROUTINE SETELM
USE element
IMPLICIT NONE

LTYPE=PROEL(ISETS)%LTYPE

SELECT CASE(LTYPE)

  CASE( 1)
    ...
  CASE( 2)
    ...
  CASE DEFAULT
    ...
END SELECT
END SUBROUTINE
```

Now, between the assignment LTYPE=PROEL(ISETS)%LTYPE and the SELECT CASE(LTYPE), the variable LTYPE changes value without any reason. The value is random (in the sense that I do not know where it comes from but it is not like uninitialized vars) and there are no others operations in the middle that work with LTYPE.

I am working with VS2008 and Fortran, so I turned on every warning, but neither compilation nor runtime give some possible hint.

Do you have any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Do you run it in debug mode? What debugging options did you try?

Comment: What fortran compiler and what version of that compiler are you using?  I recall gfortran 4.7 for example, having issues exactly like this with members of allocatable derived types (and the fix was updating to a version that properly supported allocatable derived types)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the assignment.  Execute the assignment.  From the instructions executed find out the address of LTYPE.  Set a data breakpoint on LTYPE.  Continue running your program, see where it stops.

Comment: @casey I am using Intel Visual Fortran Compiler 11.0.072, for 64bit programs.

Comment: @VladimirF I running the debug version in visual studio, with full debug informations, all warning from compile time diagnostics, all checks on in runtime.

Comment: @IanH I can find the location of the variable by using LOC(LTYPE) and setting the bytecount to 8, since I am using that kind of integers. the program does not stop for any change of LTYPE or PROEL(ISETS)%LTYPE besides those ones that are doing right. The actual "unexpected" change that I am experiencing is not catched.

Comment: @L.B. That is a fairly dated version of IVF.  I use very similar constructs in some of my own code, which work as expected with ifort 13 and 14.  Do you have a newer compiler to test against?  Alternatively if you have a minimal testcase that does not work for you I am happy to test it on a newer version of ifort.